# Angular2 bind event / DOM in ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, angular, typescript

What is the best way to accomplish toggling div visibility inside ngFor like in example bellow? Each click should toggle div visibility from same iteration. The question is actually how to bind this event/DOM properly.

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes; let i = index">
  <div [hidden]="?">Toggle my visibility</div>
  <div (click)="?">Click me</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution will be to create another array with visibility properties. So, an array (each hero visible on load):

```
this.heroesVisibility = new Array(this.heroes.length).fill(true);
```

And the function in component class:

```
public toggleVisibility(id : number) : void {
    this.heroesVisibility = !this.heroesVisibility;
}
```

Then in template:

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes; let i = index">
  <div [hidden]="!heroesVisibility[i]">Toggle my visibility</div>
  <div (click)="toggleVisibility(i)">Click me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, it looks ugly, but it is the only way if you do not want to create another component. Much better will be to create e.g HeroVisibilityComponent, which could has toggleVisibility() method, @Input() hero and visibility property. It is more in Angular 2 way :)

Answer (score 0):

Make it an *ngIf="".. Make a boolean variable and change it on click.

[Link to docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/displaying-data.html#ngIf)